# How to add a Visual Edit Shortcut to a theme mod?

Tags: theme-customizer

I've seen the example for adding a shortcut to the `blogname`:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'blogname' )->transport = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'blogname', array(
    'selector' => '.site-title',
    'render_callback' => 'blogname_render_func',
) );
```

However, how do you do that for a **theme mod**?

In my theme, I add a theme mod via [Kirki](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kirki/) like so:

```
Kirki::add_config('opts', array(
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'option_type' => 'theme_mod',
));

Kirki::add_field('opts', array(
    'settings' => 'button_navigation',
    'type'     => 'toggle',
));
```

However, when I try:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'button_navigation' )->transport = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'button_navigation', array(
    'selector' => '.menu-button',
    'render_callback' => 'my_nav_render',
) );
```

I get:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Which is expected, considering I'm adding a *theme mod* instead of a *setting* while using `get_setting()`.

If I try something like:

```
$wp_customize->get_theme_mod( 'button_navigation' )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Customize_Manager::get_theme_mod()

If I remove the part where I set `transport = 'postMessage'`, the shortcut icon appears at the right place in the Customizer preview and clicking on it takes you to the correct controller. However, when you modify the value, the whole page refreshes, instead of just the partial. I'm sure it's because I don't change the `transport` type. **How do I change it?**

Comment: A “setting” in the Customizer is a construct that _models_ objects in WordPress. By default it actually already models a theme mod. You have to specifically indicate if it is modeling an option instead by supplying the `type` param. I have not used Kirki, however, so I can't speak to how it wraps the Customizer API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the partial refresh feature of kirki

```
'transport' => 'postMessage',
    'partial_refresh' => array( 
    'my_nav_render_setting' => array( 
        'selector' => '.menu-button', 
        'render_callback' => 'my_nav_render', 
    ) ),
```